# 'end' expected near '<eof>' error in my code

Tags: lua

how can i fix `'end' expected near '<eof>'`? I tried putting end at the last line of the code, also at elseifs, and it still shows this error. (I am really new to lua by the way).

```
repeat wait() until game.workspace:FindFirstChild("NPC")
wait(2)
if game.PlaceID == 3541987450 then
print("KHEI")
for i, v in pairs(game.Workspace:GetChildren()) do
    if v.Name == "DevilRoom" then
        if v.BrickColor == BrickColor.new("Dark stone grey") and v.Position ~= Vector3.new(-1283.07092, 1164.82434, -2338.98315, 0.0816411376, -0, -0.996661782, 0, 1, -0, 0.996661782, 0, 0.0816411376) then
game.StarterGui:SetCore("SendNotification", {
    Title = "COLLECTOR";
    Text = "HE SPAWNED" .. "\n" .. "[Plains]";
        Duration = 10000;
})

a = Instance.new("Sound")
a.SoundId = "rbxassetid://39518470341"
a.Parent = game.Lighting
a.Volume = 3
a:Play()

elseif v.BrickColor == BrickColor.new("Bronze") and v.Position ~= Vector3.new(-2604.72559, 1097.82373, 1475.93469, 0.995581567, -0, -0.0939007998, 0, 1, -0, 0.0939007998, 0, 0.995581567) then
    game.StarterGui:SetCore("SendNotification", {
        Title = "COLLECTOR";
        Text = "HE SPAWNED" .. "\n" .. "[Jungle]";
        Duration = 10000;
    })
a = Instance.new("Sound")   
a.SoundId = "rbxassetid://3951847031"
a.Parent = game.Lighting
a.Volume = 3
a:Play()
elseif v.BrickColor == BrickColor.new("Fawn brown") and v.Position ~= Vector3.new(-1546.47192, 363.750061, 2445.54663, 0.999748111, 0, 0.0224423129, 0, 1, 0, -0.0224423129, 0, 0.999748111) then
    game.StarterGui:SetCore("SendNotification", {
        Title = "COLLECTOR";
        Text = "HE SPAWNED" .. "\n" .. "[Desert]";
        Duration = 10000;
})
a = Instance.new("Sound")   
a.SoundId = "rbxassetid://3951847031"
a.Parent = game.Lighting
a.Volume = 3
a:Play()
```

Comment: The complete error message is `'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 7) near <eof>`.

Comment: As correctly answered, the Lua compiler expects `end` to terminate each `for` and `if` blocks, otherwise it got confused. But in addition, the indentation of the code is incoherent, which also confuses humans that would try to read or fix that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`if` blocks](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.1.html) in Lua are terminated with `end`. Similarly [`for` loops](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html) are terminated with `end`. You'll need to add them where appropriate in your script; it doesn't look like you're using them at all currently.

The error message mentioning `<eof>` is a little confusing; it's saying "the parser was looking for an `end` but it reached the end-of-the-file and never saw one". *Not* "you need to put an `end` at the end of the file".